# How does the Russian invasion of Ukraine affect ISS operations?

Tags: iss, russia, international-politics

I realise this question may be shut down as opinion-based, but here goes anyway.

With diplomatic relations in the toilet following Russian military activity in Ukraine, how will this affect future operations on the International Space Station? Will we see a situation like the one in the film *2010* where the Soviet and American crews were ordered not to interact with each other? And how about the upcoming missions?

Comment: I think there is a good, factually answerable question in here (if only from a Western perspective)

Comment: No because it doesn't matter.

Comment: This can have fact-based answers that draw from whatever did or didn't happen in 2014 for example, so **voting to leave open**

Comment: Contrary to @uhoh, I am voting to close. (And once again, you cannot vote to leave open. You can only not vote to close.) As of now, there is no telling what the outcome will be. The question is unanswerable at this moment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a current event for which the outcome is highly uncertain. It might become more clear in a week or even month from now, but as it stands, the question as of now is unanswerable.

Comment: @DavidHammen that's a made-up close reason in my opinion, but you can always leave an answer to [What's best to do about questions that might not be answerable for a few months?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/12102)

Comment: That is your opinion, @uhoh. However, StackExchange across the board allows for what you call "made-up" close reasons. That you don't like that option is your opinion. Do note that your opinion is contrary to how this site operates, along with how almost every other StackExhcange site operates.

Comment: @DavidHammen  evidence that closing questions that can be answered in a week or even month from now is how almost every other StackExhcange site operates? We just don't do that.

Comment: @uoh That's the royal "we" you are using. You might  no do so, but I do  do so -- along with two others on this question alone. I've been joined with four others (or I have joined four others) on multiple occasions, on multiple StackExchange sites. I do not like what I consider to be bad questions.

Comment: [The Russian invasion of Ukraine will have myriad impacts on spaceflight](https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/02/the-russian-invasion-of-ukraine-will-have-myriad-impacts-on-spaceflight/). *NASA issued a measured response on Thursday evening, saying it was continuing to work with Russia and its partners to safely fly the International Space Station. "The new export control measures will continue to allow US-Russia civil space cooperation," the agency said. "No changes are planned to the agency’s support for ongoing in-orbit and ground station operations."*

Comment: [Russia pulls out of European spaceport, abandoning a planned launch](https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/02/russia-pulls-out-of-european-spaceport-abandoning-a-planned-launch/).

Comment: [US and allies block tech exports to Russia in response to invasion of Ukraine](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2022/02/us-and-allies-block-tech-exports-to-russia-in-response-to-invasion-of-ukraine/).

Comment: [Dmitry Rogozin says he does not appreciate “openly hostile” US policy](https://arstechnica.com/science/2022/02/russias-space-chief-is-very-unhappy-with-hostile-us-policy/). *Preserving Russia's partnership with NASA is important because, absent the International Space Station, his country really has no human spaceflight program.* *An argument could be made that Russia has even more to lose, as Roscosmos' budget hinges more on the space station than does NASA's* *Russia has rejected the Artemis program and said it will probably join China's lunar exploration efforts.*

Comment: [ESA continues with ExoMars](https://www.esa.int/About_Us/Corporate_news/Crisis_in_Ukraine)

Comment: @BojanKogoj: As of 28 Feb 2022, [not any more](https://www.esa.int/Newsroom/Press_Releases/ESA_statement_regarding_cooperation_with_Russia_following_a_meeting_with_Member_States_on_28_February_2022). The launch of ExoMars in 2022 seems unlikely.

Comment: There can certainly be fact-based answers here as discussed above, and opinion-based answers are routinely handled quickly and painlessly here. No reason to block everyone and anyone from an opportunity to post an answer in this case. **voting to leave open**

Comment: Scott Manley's [The Ways Russia's Invasion Ukraine Will Affect Space Programs - Deep Space Updates Feb 27th](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V-lj-jCqe8) **voting to reopen!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer here is... it probably won't change much. The ISS has been around since 1998. Since then Russia has invaded the Republic of Georgia (2008) and seized Crimea from Ukraine (2014). NASA [put out this statement](https://www.space.com/russia-ukraine-nasa-response-iss-operations) in regards to the 2022 invasion of Ukraine

> "NASA continues working with all our international partners, including the State Space Corporation Roscosmos, for the ongoing safe operations of the International Space Station. The new export control measures will continue to allow U.S.-Russia civil space cooperation. No changes are planned to the agency’s support for ongoing in orbit and ground station operations," NASA said in a statement today that agency spokesperson Joshua Finch emailed to Space.com.

---

> Will we see a situation like the one in the film 2010 where the Soviet and American crews were ordered not to interact with each other?

There's a key difference here. In the movie, you have a separate Soviet spacecraft and an American spacecraft. Neither had to interact with the other to function (fun fact: it was a Soviet mission to the American spacecraft that got them there in the first place).

The ISS has both American and Russian components and [you need both parts to make the ISS work](https://www.cnn.com/2022/02/24/politics/russian-space-agency-us-sanctions-international-space-station/index.html)

> "The Russian segment can't function without the electricity on the American side, and the American side can't function without the propulsion systems that are on the Russian side," former NASA astronaut Garrett Reisman told CNN. "So you can't do an amicable divorce. You can't do a conscious uncoupling."

All of this relies on there not being a "hot" war (i.e. both sides are fighting with one another). If that were to happen, I would say the worst-case scenario would be one side abandoning its part of the ISS. That wouldn't immediately threaten the ISS (both sides can send personnel and supplies up by themselves), but the lack of ongoing support for the other end could hamper its operation.

Comment: Of course, today the head of Roscomos is threatening to crash the ISS into the US, India, China, or Europe. He probably needs some trampoline exercise to calm down. https://ktvz.com/news/2022/02/25/head-of-russian-space-agency-appears-to-threaten-to-drop-iss-on-india-or-china/

Comment: @OrganicMarble Considering that [the Russians endangered their own people with an ill-advised destruction of a satellite a few weeks ago](https://www.space.com/crussian-anti-satellite-missile-test-world-condemnation), I would say a simple exercise won't be enough.

Comment: According to [Scott Manley video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5lidnLtO7c) it takes quite an effort to do controlled deorbit, not just a push of a button.

Comment: Bottom line appears to be "We don't know" but the quote posted by Machavity seems to provide our best guess at the moment.